# how to resolve the error" ImportError: cannot import name 'HIDE_CURSOR' " in python 3.6.5

Tags: python-3.6

when I am installing a package in python 3.6.5 an error occurs:

> "ImportError: cannot import name 'HIDE_CURSOR'"

command: `pip install`

> pip install glob Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
>       "**main**", mod_spec)   File "c:\python\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
>       exec(code, run_globals)   File "C:\python\Scripts\pip.exe__main__.py", line 5, in    File
>   "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip_internal__init__.py", line 40, in
>   
>       from pip._internal.cli.autocompletion import autocomplete   File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\autocompletion.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from pip._internal.cli.main_parser import create_main_parser   File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\main_parser.py",
>   line 8, in 
>       from pip._internal.cli import cmdoptions   File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\cli\cmdoptions.py", line
>   24, in 
>       from pip._internal.utils.ui import BAR_TYPES   File "c:\python\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\utils\ui.py", line 11, in
>   
>       from pip._vendor.progress import HIDE_CURSOR, SHOW_CURSOR ImportError: cannot import name 'HIDE_CURSOR'

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I simply reinstalled pip by downloading pip from [here](https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py) and reinstalled using cmd `python get-pip.py`once in the directory.

Thats all that seemed to work for me, hope you get it sorted!